# Regular expression to match last and first number number in a output file

Tags: python, regex

I have two sets up output files. I want to capture the first number after the Virtual and last number before the virtual. I found the regex for the first output:

```py
rx_orb = re.compile(
    r'''(?P<HOMO>-?\d.\d{3}$)((.*\n){,2})\s*(.*?Virtual.*$\s*?)(?P<LUMO>-?\d.\d{3})''',
    re.MULTILINE)
```

But this regex is not working for the second one. in addition, when I use the first 2 lines in the  output1, it extracts the wrong number for `Homo`:

```
LUMO:  0.028
HOMO:  -0.448
```

How can I find the regex that works for both output files?
I bold the numbers that I need below:

```
-0.824  -0.732  -0.715  -0.694  -0.627  -0.619  -0.607  -0.571
 -0.544  -0.518  -0.504  -0.495  -0.495  -0.477  -0.453  -0.448
 -0.422  -0.379  -0.370  -0.325  -0.305  **-0.263**
 -- Virtual --
  **0.028**   0.072   0.109   0.163   0.188   0.191   0.199   0.215
  0.239   0.266   0.277   0.278   0.296   0.322   0.348   0.363
  0.399   0.409   0.431   0.439   0.448   0.539   0.557   0.593
```

```
 9 Au    9 Ag   10 Au   10 Ag   11 Ag   11 Au   12 Ag   13 Ag                 
-0.497  -0.482  -0.478  -0.447  -0.415  -0.410  -0.407  -0.362
12 Au   13 Au   14 Au   15 Au   14 Ag   15 Ag   16 Ag   17 Ag                 
-0.313  **-0.284**
16 Au   17 Au                                                                 
-- Virtual --                   
 **0.031**   0.062   0.111   0.177   0.186   0.197   0.206   0.253
18 Ag   19 Ag   18 Au   20 Ag   19 Au   20 Au   21 Au   21 Ag                 
 0.256   0.261   0.267   0.292   0.295   0.327   0.366   0.391
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you use this regex in your code? Maybe you forgot to set [re.MULTILINE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE) flag when working with strings?

This example works as expected:

```py
import re

TEXT1 = """-0.422  -0.379  -0.370  -0.325  -0.305  -0.263
-- Virtual --
0.028   0.072   0.109   0.163   0.188   0.191   0.199   0.215
0.239   0.266   0.277   0.278   0.296   0.322   0.348   0.363
"""

TEXT2 = """9 Au    9 Ag   10 Au   10 Ag   11 Ag   11 Au   12 Ag   13 Ag
-0.497  -0.482  -0.478  -0.447  -0.415  -0.410  -0.407  -0.362
12 Au   13 Au   14 Au   15 Au   14 Ag   15 Ag   16 Ag   17 Ag
-0.313  -0.284
16 Au   17 Au
-- Virtual --
 0.031   0.062   0.111   0.177   0.186   0.197   0.206   0.253
18 Ag   19 Ag   18 Au   20 Ag   19 Au   20 Au   21 Au   21 Ag
 0.256   0.261   0.267   0.292   0.295   0.327   0.366   0.391
"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_re = r'(?P<HOMO>-?\d.\d{3}$)((.*\n){,2})\s*(.*?Virtual.*$\s*?)(?P<LUMO>-?\d.\d{3})'
    m = re.search(my_re, TEXT1, re.MULTILINE)
    print(m.groupdict())
    m = re.search(my_re, TEXT2, re.MULTILINE)
    print(m.groupdict())
```

Output:

```
{'HOMO': '-0.263', 'LUMO': '0.028'}
{'HOMO': '-0.284', 'LUMO': '0.031'}
```

**Update:**

However, you may encounter problems when using Python 2 and reading files with dos-style linebreaks (`^M`). In this case you need to consider that linebreaks will contain additional carriage return symbol `\r`. You should use `\r\n` to find linebreaks and consider using [re.DOTALL](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) option which allow you match newlines with dot (`.`) symbol.

A rough solution may be removing all `\r` symbols after reading from file, e.g.:

```py
    with open('file-windows-linebreaks.txt') as f:
        data = f.read()
        data = data.replace('\r\n', '\n')
        # Use regex on data
```

After this replacement your regex works correctly.

By the way, this behavior was fixed in Python 3 [open](https://docs.python.org/release/3.2/library/functions.html#open). According documentation, `open` has an universal `newline` parameter:

```
newline controls how universal newlines works (it only applies to text mode).
It can be None, '', '\n', '\r', and '\r\n'.
```

So your regex will works in Python 3 without any additional actions.

Comment: Actually I did, here is the way that I used the regex `rx_orb = re.compile(r'''(?P<HOMO>-?\d.\d{3}$)((.*\n){,2})\s*(.*?Virtual.*$\s*?)(?P<LUMO>-?\d.\d{3})''',re.MULTILINE)            . but for the second output I've got this error:                                                                                          `4 orb_res = rx_orb.search(final_string)
      5 
----> 6 lumo = float(orb_res.group('LUMO'))
      7 print('LUMO: ', lumo)
      8 homo = float(orb_res.group('HOMO'))

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' `

Comment: It seems that problem not in regex, because the minimal example works. May be your input data differs? Or you process results incorrectly?

Comment: Thanks, But the code is working fine in other section and I could extract my results. The problem only occurs in this section. and I don't know why??

Comment: wow. I changed the (r''' >to r') and it works. Do you know why? Thanks

Comment: ... are you using Python2?

Comment: yes, I also checked when I use the first 2 line {,2}, it extracts the wrong number for HOMO the first output file: LUMO:  0.028
HOMO:  -0.448

Comment: What does it mean: "when I use the first 2 line {,2}"? Can you show code after this change?

Comment: Really, it doesn't work when I change `r''` to `r''''''` with Python 2, but still works in Python 3. It somewhat strange, need to figure out.

Comment: Hmm. I can reproduce this error with dos-style linebreaks (`^M`)... Are you on Windows?

Comment: I extended my answer. It seems that this regex is work correctly in all possible cases.

Comment: Sorry, for my late response. It was late at night here. Thanks for your explanation. I understand your point. and the code is working now. I am using Python 3. But there is one question. if you use the output file with more than one line above the Virtual for the case one, you cannot get the right answer. can you please check this? I updated my question and I add more lines to output one. in most of my files, I have more than 10 lines above "virtual" and choosing between 2 lines give me the wrong answers.{,2}. Do you know how can I fix this problem?

Comment: I wrote '  rx_orb = re.compile(r'''(?P<HOMO>-?\d.\d{3}$).*?Virtual.*$\s*?(?P<LUMO>-?\d.\d{3})''',re.MULTILINE) ' but this gives me the error when I am using second output.

Comment: Try this one: `rx_orb = re.compile(r'(?P<HOMO>-?\d.\d{3}$).*?Virtual.*$\s*?(?P<LUMO>-?\d.\d{3})', re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)`. `re.DOTALL` will make `.*` capture newlines, so your new regex will work as expected.